# Noise on microscopy data

Tags: matlab, noise, video-processing

I have to analyze beating cardiomyocytes. In order to do so, I have written a Matlab script to replicate the method found in Béland et al., Front. Physiol. (2022) (doi: doi.org/10.3389/fphys.2022.733706).

Briefly, for each time point, the algorithm calculates the module of the difference between the intensity of each corresponding pixel at different, constant, timeframes. Such value is then averaged amongst all pixels (equation 1 in the paper).

The Matlab script is this one:

```
videoObj = VideoReader(VideoPath);
% Show the first frame
frameOne = readFrame(videoObj);
hf = figure;
set(hf, 'position', [150 150 videoObj.Width videoObj.Height]);
imshow(frameOne);
% Select ROI
try
    ROI = drawrectangle;
    wait(ROI);
    posROI=round(ROI.Position);
catch
    warning('Select a roi!');
    return;
end
close(hf);
% Initialize variables
numFrames = videoObj.NumFrames;
tau=3;
brightnessMatrix = zeros(posROI(4)+1,posROI(3)+1,numFrames); %add 1 to have the same dimensions of brightnessValues
brightnessMatrixDifference = zeros(posROI(4)+1,posROI(3)+1,numFrames); %add 1 to have the same dimensions of brightnessValues
brightnessMatrixDifferenceAveraged = zeros(numFrames,1);
% Iterate through all frames and extract the brightness values for the ROI
for k = 1:(numFrames-1)
    frame = readFrame(videoObj);
    roiFrame = frame(posROI(2):(posROI(2) + posROI(4)), posROI(1):(posROI(1) + posROI(3)), :);
    brightnessValues = mean(roiFrame, 3); % Compute mean brightness across color channels
    brightnessMatrix(:, :, k) = brightnessValues; % Store brightness values in the matrix
end
for k = (tau+1):(numFrames-1)
brightnessMatrixDifference(:,:,k) = abs(brightnessMatrix(:,:,k)-brightnessMatrix(:,:,k-tau))/tau;
end

for k = (tau+1):(numFrames-1)
brightnessMatrixDifferenceAveraged(k) = mean(brightnessMatrixDifference(:,:,k),'all');
end
```

Now, the problem is that, when there are no cells beating and the video looks exactly still, I obtain a cycling signal at around 1 cycle per second (Figure 1). This video is 8 seconds long and it has a frame rate of 32 fps. [image: This image shows a cycling pattern of around 1 cycle/second, even if no cells are beating.]

Of course I can filter out this noise, but I would like to know what could cause this phenomenon,